# Problems getting even basic javascript to work [noob here]

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to learn javascript. I've gone through a few tutorials and guides, however often they don't teach you how to write javascript to work with web pages.

What I want to learn how to do is provide some basic interactivity with websites I've been making recently. While they contain dynamic content, I still would like some of the interactivity of javascript. All of my attempts have been futile, however, as nothing works. My end goal is to get my websites feeling more professional, and maybe also get a node.js server up and running with some ajax or websockets going to perhaps build a 2d game with canvas, but that is much much later.

The following code is some basic things I've written based on some HTML DOM tutorials I've read. The problem is it doesn't work at all. So can anyone tell me what is going on here, about why it doesn't work at all. And yes, I do have javascript turned on in my browser.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
    <p>SomeText</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ptag = document.getElementById('p');

        function alertclick() {
            alert(this);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < ptag.length; i++){
            var attach = ptag[i];
            attach.addEventListener("click", alertclick, false);
        }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JFGI. http://www.google.com/insidesearch/tipstricks/

Comment: There is no such error as "doesn't work".  You expected it to do one thing and it did something else, but you didn't tell us either of those things.

Comment: @isANoob Check out http://www.codecademy.com. That will really get you going.

Comment: I've been using Node.js a lot and would also like to create a multiplayer canvas game. In terms of tools which could help you:
Socket.IO, Express.js, Crafty.js, and for the canvas... FabricJS or KinectJS

Answer (score 6):

That's because you're using `getElementById` and the is no element with the id `p`. Instead use `getElementsByTagName` to get all `p` elements.

```
var ptags = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0; i < ptags.length; i++){
     var element = ptags[i];
     element.addEventListener("click", alertclick, false);
}
```

Comment: So the answer throughout learning javascript is become more familiar with the methods for different objects? So far it feels rather c-like and I have some experience with c++, but it seems what is tripping me up is knowing what is already there to work with.

Comment: Yes, it may seem overwhelming at first but you have to learn the basics of accessing/searching the DOM, DOM traversal and manipulation. Here's a good reference http://javascript.info/tutorial/searching-elements-dom#methods

Comment: @isANoob, javascript is not about learning method names  and what they do. That's called learning an API (in this case the DOM API), which is what you need to do if you want to play with the DOM. Learning new APIs is something that you'll want to be able to do with any language that you intend to use to actually build something. Learning javascript is about learning about closures, objects and scope, among other things.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few things that will catch you out as a beginner.

1. When the JavaScript runs before the page has loaded.
2. The order in which you include JavaScript files in the page is important.
3. The number of ways in which you can do something.

## Plain JavaScript:

In your code i'm assuming that you're trying to access all `<p>` tags, you can use `getElemenysByTagName('p')`.

If you would like to access a single element I recommend assigning an ID to it as so `<p id="me">SomeText</p>` and then use `getElementsById('me')`.

If you wan't to access a set of elements, but not all of a certain type you should apply a class `<p class="group">SomeText</p>`... you can use `getElementsByClassName('group')` but it's only supported in more modern browsers.

For Selection of elements I strongly recommend using jQuery, it makes the process much easier and more flexible. http://jquery.com/

## jQuery:

Once using jQuery you can access elements as so:

```
$('#me'); //Individual Element by ID
$('.group'); //Group of elements by Class
$('<p>'); //All P elements
```

jQuery is also very good when creating event handlers because of it's simplicity and cross-browser compatibility. For your onClick:

http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 3):

Have some confidence! You are almost there. This is the behavior I understood you want: click on a paragraph to alert its contents.

We like showing a working demo in both questions and answers: http://jsfiddle.net/bxvny/

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
    <p>SomeText</p>
    <p>SomeText2</p>
    <p>SomeText3</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ptag = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

        function alertclick() {
            alert(this.innerHTML);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < ptag.length; i++){
            var attach = ptag[i];
            attach.addEventListener("click", alertclick, false);
        }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```